# animate -height to bottom instead of to top

Tags: objective-c, animation

I want to decrease the height of my imageview to 0. I tried this with this piece of code. 
My code is working, but the imageview decreases the height from the bottom to the top, but I want, that the animation is from top to bottom.

Is there a function to reach that? And is there also a solution for a slightly bouncing at the end of an animation?

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
    _Image.frame = CGRectMake(5, 120, 35, 0);
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
_Image.frame = CGRectMake(5, 120, 35, 0);

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    // OR
    [_Image layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should animate `_Image.frame.origin.y` together with `_Image.frame.size.height`:

```
CGFloat initialImageHeight = _Image.frame.size.height;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
    _Image.frame = CGRectMake(5, 120 - initialImageHeight, 35, 0);
}];
```